# find and replace in multiple workbooks vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I'm copying Sheet 1 to multiple identical workbooks in 1 folder. When I do this, the formulas in Sheet 1 remain dependent on the source workbook. I'd like to remove that dependency so I'm trying to find and replace the connecting strings with "". Due to the volume of files, it isn't feasible to do so 1x1 - which is why I'm looking for some VBA help.

I do have the code to copy Sheet1 to all workbooks in the folder. And I have found a piece of code RE: find and replace. But I dont know how to piece them together.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CopySheetToAllWorkbooksInFolder()

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim folder As String, filename As String
    Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook

    'Worksheet in active workbook to be copied as a new sheet to the destination woorkbook

    Set sourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Folder containing the destination workbooks

    folder = "'C:\Users\FOLDERLOCATION\[FILENAME.xlsm]"

    filename = Dir(folder & "*.xls", vbNormal)
    While Len(filename) <> 0
        Debug.Print folder & filename
        Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folder & filename)
        sourceSheet.Copy before:=destinationWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        destinationWorkbook.Close True
        filename = Dir()  ' Get next matching file

 Wend
 End Sub
```

the code I have for the copy/replace

```
fnd = "'C:\Users\FOLDERLOCATION\[FILENAME.xlsm]"
rplc = ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it that in your source workbook in `Sheet1` there are Formulas that reference cells on other sheets in the source workbook.  Lets say `=Sheet2!A1` or similar.  On the assumption that the destination workbooks contain sheets with the *same names* as those referenced in the source workbook, you can use the `Workbook.ChangeLink` method to update the copied sheets.

Note:
 1. your `folder` value looks suspect.  I've substituted a valid path on my system to demo the correct format.
 2. I've used `*.xls*` in my Dir function.  Revert to `*.xls` if you want.

```
Public Sub CopySheetToAllWorkbooksInFolder()
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook, sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim folder As String, filename As String
    Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook

    'Worksheet in active workbook to be copied as a new sheet to the destination woorkbook
    Set sourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set sourceWB = sourceSheet.Parent

    'Folder containing the destination workbooks
    folder = "C:\Data\Temp\SO\Test\" ' "'C:\Users\FOLDERLOCATION\[FILENAME.xlsm]"

    filename = Dir(folder & "*.xls*", vbNormal)
    Do While Len(filename) <> 0
        Debug.Print folder & filename
        Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folder & filename)
        sourceSheet.Copy Before:=destinationWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        destinationWorkbook.ChangeLink _
          Name:=sourceWB.Name, _
          NewName:=destinationWorkbook.Name, _
          Type:=xlExcelLinks
        destinationWorkbook.Close True
        filename = Dir()  ' Get next matching file
    Loop
 End Sub
```

Comment: Chris! Way to go! This is maybe one of the most exciting things ever!!!
Thank you so much - this worked perfectly.
I really appreciate your helping a newbie out